# Simplify the nested double loop when compare index(i<j)

Tags: loops, for-loop

I need to calculate the following formula:

> $ \sum_{i < j}=f( x[i], x[j] )$

I can finish this with a double loop, like:

```
result = 0
for(j in 1:n){
  for(i in 1:n){
    if(i<j) result = result + f(x[i],x[j])
}}
```

However, I wonder is there any more efficient way to do this? Like use one loop instead nested loop?

Comment: Hint: look at the upper bound for the inner loop. You don't want `i` to go from `1` to `n`, you want it to go from `1` to...?

Comment: Thanks, that's great. The upper bound should be j instead n. Is there any way to simplify this to one loop?